# Is there a reason to make weapons from blueprints rather than crafting them manually?

Tags: dead-space-3

After a trip to the Wiki I learned that guns like the Contact Beam and Line Gun are now really just combinations of frames, tools and tips, like the Plasma Core + Default Tip + Light Frame = Plasma Cutter. At first I had been creating weapons from blueprints and slapping components on them afterwards.

Is there any reason to construct guns from blueprints rather than crafting them from parts? It seems like building them from parts will allow more versatility, as I'll keep adding exchangeable parts instead of whole, default guns. Are blueprint guns cheaper or better somehow, or is it just an easy way to make a gun without knowing which parts to combine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructing from blueprints just automatically creates a pre-set gun for you from your available weapon parts and resources. If you don't have the weapon parts or resources that a blueprint needs, you still won't be able to construct the gun from a blueprint, like if you're constructing a gun manually. I don't think it allows for a "cheaper" gun.

It's a good way of experimenting on what gun parts do and what kinds of guns you can build, though. Also, if you prefer the classic Dead Space 1 and 2 guns, you can just easily build them from blueprints. Like manually constructed guns, guns constructed from blueprints can be dismantled (so you get the parts back), and modified, if you like the gun you got and would like to improve/tweak it a bit.

If you want more control over your resources, avoid creating weapons from blueprints, as it will automatically create a weapon part from your resources if a blueprint requires a part that you currently don't have. You might want to just look up what parts make up a blueprint at a Dead Space wiki site, instead. From the Dead Space Wiki's "[Dead Space 3 Weapons](http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/Dead_Space_3_Weapons)" article:

> Blueprints do the assembly work for you, but do not add anything you can't make using the manual assembly interface. A blueprint will use any matching parts that you already have before producing new parts using resources. If you have some parts, but not all, it will use the parts you have and then use resources to make the rest. Parts already being used by weapons in your safe will not be used, so if you want to use those you should either disassemble those weapons first or just modify the weapon manually.

An advantage of collecting blueprints is (From the [IGN Dead Space 3 wiki, "Blueprints" article](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dead-space-3/Blueprints)):

> Once the player finds all the blue prints they will get special Upgrade Circuits. These Upgrade Circuits include:
>
> +3 Fire Rate, +2 Damage
>
> +3 Reload, +3 Clip

Comment: I was wondering if they used parts I already had; I noticed some are free and some are pretty expensive and I wondered if that was the cause